# Error with open-uri on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, paperclip

I'm using the code below to open and upload a Facebook profile image to S3 using Paperclip. The code works fine on my localhost (Rails 3.1, ruby 1.9.2 p290) but it breaks on heroku (bamboo-mri-1.9.2)

```
facebook_image_url = access_token['user_info']['image'].gsub("square", "large")
url = URI.parse(facebook_image_url)

#Follow the redirect of Facebook profile picture url
res = Net::HTTP.start(url.host, url.port) { |http|
  http.get(facebook_image_url)
}

signed_in_resource.avatar = open(res['location'])
signed_in_resource.save
signed_in_resource
```

Does anyone have any suggestion?

Comment: It might have something to do with Heroku's read-only file system. Maybe open-uri is trying to create a temporary file of some sort? I don't know it for a fact that this is the reason, but it could be worth checking.

Comment: I had a similar issue with S3 URL's. I noticed that a lot of them, due to the filenames of the files uploaded had spaces thoughout. Running URI.escape('url to my picture.jpg') sorted things out though so might be worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

I have hade similar problems solved the issue by using an updated version of URLTempfile. Also using S3 as image storage.

https://github.com/chris/paperclip_url_support, put in lib folder of your installation.

```
product = Product.first(:conditions => {:_id => self.product_id})
raise "Unable to get product with id #{self.product_id}" unless product
product.picture = URLTempfile.new(self.image_url)
product.save!
```

Using this in production on heroku with same config as you. (Heroku 1.9.3, Rails 3.1).

Hope this helps you.